# Contextual Menu issue in office-fabric-ui on second click

Tags: javascript, office-ui-fabric

We are working on Office UI Fabric JS 1.2.0. Issue is with context menu having submenu items. When you open Second level, and then click anywhere on menu, first level menu was closing and second menu was re-aligning to Top-Left of page. We couldn't find the solution in next version of fabric also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue gets resolved after overriding two methods from fabric.js of `ContextualHost` as follows:

```
fabric.ContextualHost.prototype.disposeModal = function () {
    if (fabric.ContextualHost.hosts.length > 0) {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this._resizeAction, false);
        document.removeEventListener("click", this._dismissAction, true);
        document.removeEventListener("keyup", this._handleKeyUpDismiss, true);
        this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);
        if (this._disposalCallback) {
            this._disposalCallback();
        }
        // Dispose of all ContextualHosts
        var index = fabric.ContextualHost.hosts.indexOf(this);
        fabric.ContextualHost.hosts.splice(index, 1);

        //Following is original code removed
        //var i = ContextualHost.hosts.length;
        //while (i--) {
        //    ContextualHost.hosts[i].disposeModal();
        //    ContextualHost.hosts.splice(i, 1);
        //}
    }
};

fabric.ContextualHost.prototype._dismissAction = function (e) {

    var i = fabric.ContextualHost.hosts.length;
    while (i--) { //New added
        var currentHost = fabric.ContextualHost.hosts[i];
        if (!currentHost._container.contains(e.target) && e.target !== this._container) {
            if (currentHost._children !== undefined) {
                var isChild_1 = false;
                currentHost._children.map(function (child) {
                    if (child !== undefined) {
                        isChild_1 = child.contains(e.target);
                    }
                });
                if (!isChild_1) {
                    currentHost.disposeModal();
                }
            }
            else {
                currentHost.disposeModal();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this question + answer helps someone looking to override fabric.js original code.